# Позиционирование компонента на странице

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap5

Имеется вот такая структура:

```
<Row>
    <Col sm={8}>
        <Component_1/>
    </Col>
    <Col sm={4}>
        <Component_2/>
    </Col>
<Row>
```

Как сделать так, что бы при прокрутке страницы Component_2 оставался на месте?

Comment: position: fixed?

Comment: @nannik, В таком случае он смещается и накладывается на первый компонент. А нужно, что бы компонент_2 не выходил за пределы своего <Col sm={4}>